# How can I stop NPCs from picking up my dropped items?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I would like to decorate my home in Skyrim (Blackthorn manor, from the Blackthorn mod). I have one problem though: if I drop anything when a follower or my steward is nearby, they pick it up and give it back to me.

Is there any way to stop this behavior? It makes it virtually impossible for me to get any decorating done.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

It appears that these are all World Interactions (see [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/World_Interactions_(Skyrim)#Items_of_Disinterest)). [Here](https://forums.nexusmods.com/index.php?/topic/1170791-keep-npcs-from-picking-up-dropped-objects/) is a thread that involves two users discussing how one would go about making such a mod (if you're up to the task!)

---

Apparently, you *were* up to the task! [Here](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/80099/?) is a link to the impromptu mod created by @ZauberParacelsus to make NPCs ignore dropped items!

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I've made a tiny mod to tweak the NPC ai packages based on the info in that thread, and I've uploaded it to the nexus in case anyone else has a need for it: http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/80099/?

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus that's awesome, actually, I'll just go and add it to the answer if you don't mind!

Comment: Don't mind at all.  I didn't think I'd be up to the task, but once I read that thread I had a good idea of how to do it.

Comment: @ZauberParacelsus I'm glad that I was able to help!

Comment: This Q&A is too meta.

Comment: @Mindwin Too meta is "too meta for [meta.se]". Anything less meta than that should be migrated to where it's "just about meta enough".

Comment: @wizzwizz4 no, not meta-stack. Meta as in [https://xkcd.com/917/](https://xkcd.com/917/)

Comment: @Mindwin I was thinking of the "get paper rejected for being too meta" xkcd.

Comment: @Mindwin Obviously meta as in [meta.gaming.se].